# Lodash: create new array with latest items

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array as below

```
[{
        "id": "001",
        "name": "A",
        "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T11:22:19"
    },
    {
        "id": "002",
        "name": "A",
        "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T11:30:19"
    },
    {
        "id": "003",
        "name": "B",
        "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T10:15:19"
    },
    {
        "id": "004",
        "name": "B",
        "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T11:05:19"
    }
]
```

I want to create a new array based on the above array, but with only latest item, (group by name of item).

```
 [{
            "id": "002",
            "name": "A",
            "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T11:30:19"
        },
        {
            "id": "004",
            "name": "B",
            "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T11:05:19"
        }
    ]
```

How to combine different Lodash's features to achieve the result?

Any suggestion, please help me.

Comment: Latest two items? Latest item of each name What?

Comment: As example, array has 2 items (A,B) but different timestamp created, I wanna create a new array with latest A and latest B, depend on timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), collect all latest items (by checking `timestamp_created`), grouped by `name` and get the values.

```js
var data = [{ id: "002", name: "A", timestamp_created: "2019-02-27T11:30:19" }, { id: "003", name: "B", timestamp_created: "2019-02-27T10:15:19" }, { id: "004", name: "B", timestamp_created: "2019-02-27T11:05:19" }, { id: "001", name: "A", timestamp_created: "2019-02-27T11:22:19" }],
    result = Array.from(data
        .reduce(
            (m, o) => m.has(o.name) && m.get(o.name).timestamp_created > o.timestamp_created
               ? m
               : m.set(o.name, o),
            new Map
        )
        .values()
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: the amount of character saving effort though :D

Comment: I call it the Nina Factor ;)

Answer (score 2):

Without using the library `lodash`, you can generate the result using **[Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**:

```js
const input = [
    {
        "id": "001",
        "name": "A",
        "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T11:22:19"
    },
    {
        "id": "002",
        "name": "A",
        "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T11:30:19"
    },
    {
        "id": "003",
        "name": "B",
        "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T10:15:19"
    },
    {
        "id": "004",
        "name": "B",
        "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T11:05:19"
    }
];

let res = input.reduce((acc, {id, name, timestamp_created}) =>
{
    acc[name] = acc[name] || {id, name, timestamp_created};
    
    if (acc[name].timestamp_created < timestamp_created)
        acc[name] = {id, name, timestamp_created};    

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use lodash this will do the job.

```
function latestItems(original) {
    filtered = [];
    grouped = _.groupBy(original, "name");
    _.forEach(grouped, function (group) {
        newest = {
            "timestamp_created": "0"
        };
        _.forEach(group, function (item) {
            if (item.timestamp_created > newest.timestamp_created) {
                newest = item;
            }
        });
        filtered.push(newest);
    });

    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: For answering question those need some codes and scripts, a description of how the written code works must be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Great answers so far. As OP asked for a Lodash solution, here's that:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "001",
    "name": "A",
    "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T11:22:19"
},
{
    "id": "002",
    "name": "A",
    "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T11:30:19"
},
{
    "id": "003",
    "name": "B",
    "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T10:15:19"
},
{
    "id": "004",
    "name": "B",
    "timestamp_created": "2019-02-27T11:05:19"
}
];

const reduceFunction = (acc, val) => {
    if (val.name in acc) {
        if (val.timestamp_created > acc[val.name].timestamp_created) {
            acc[val.name] = val
        }
    } else {
        acc[val.name] = val
    }

    return acc;
};

const filteredData = _.values(
    _.reduce(data, reduceFunction, {})
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Short solution using lodash

```
const data = [...]
const result = _(data)
  .groupBy('name')
  .map(group => _.maxBy(group, 'timestamp_created'))
  .value()
```

---

Use `groupBy` to group by *name*. Then use `maxBy` to get object that has max *timestamp_created*.

> `_.maxBy(array, [iteratee=_.identity])`
>
> > This method is like _.max except that it accepts iteratee which is invoked for each element in array to generate the criterion by which the value is ranked. The iteratee is invoked with one argument: (value).
>
> https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#maxBy